# sort predicate is not passing references to indexed objects?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, c++14, std

I have a few parallel arrays.  I don't want to create a new array that would combine them all, so I created an index array, which I want to sort based on one of the parallel arrays contents.  However, if I try and get the index of the passed indices, they don't appear to be references to the original vector.

E.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<int> original = { 4, 3, 5, 2, 7 };
    vector<size_t> indices;
    size_t length = original.size();
    indices.reserve(length);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < original.size(); ++i) {
      indices.push_back(i);
    }

    sort(indices.begin(), indices.end()
      , [&] (size_t& lhs, size_t& rhs) {
        assert(&indices.front() <= &lhs && &lhs <= &indices.back());
        assert(&indices.front() <= &rhs && &rhs <= &indices.back());
        size_t iLhs = &lhs - &indices.front();
        size_t iRhs = &rhs - &indices.front();
        return original[iLhs] < original[iRhs];
    });

    for(auto index : indices) {
        cout << original[index] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da3a7f3f7da998a6)</kbd>

Which fails with the message:

```
a.out: main.cpp:22: main()::<lambda(size_t&, size_t&)>: Assertion `&indices.front() <= &lhs && &lhs <= &indices.back()' failed.
```

Why would this be?  Does this mean that `std::sort` creates copies of the objects when explicitly told to use a reference in the predicate?  Isn't that inefficient?

Comment: @Justin, yes, I did that before.  Wanted to ensure that I was getting the proper pointers.  Not relivant to the question.  I'll change it if it is really wanted.

Comment: `&indices.front() <= &lhs` you should not compare pointer, but value of index.

Comment: [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) might help to build `indices`.

Comment: @Jarod42, thanks for that. :)

Comment: There's no requirement that the comparator is only called with references into the range. It's perfectly valid for `std::sort` to call it on local variables within `std::sort`. That's what's happening: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf7b4d862a8cdab9

Comment: Yes, but that implies that the objects are being copied prematurely.  If I was sorting on a larger object, this would require more copies than is necessary.

Comment: `std::sort` copies nothing. It may *move* elements around and into local variables as it pleases, however.

Comment: @T.C., ok, still would be an unnecessary move.

Comment: [citation needed] on the "unnecessary" part.

Comment: @T.C, oh, I see.  It needs to move the object out in a temporary place anyway for the swapping of the elements.  But isn't it's move premature?  What happens if it doesn't need to move that element?  Then it would require that it move it back.

Comment: @Adrian It doesn't matter. The standard library implementers for your standard library decided that this algorithm is the best algorithm they can make while meeting the standard's requirements. There's no theorem in CS saying that the fastest sorting algorithms should never move objects into temporary variables. There may be sorting algorithms that *require* an external temporary variable. Why should we expect the standard library to avoid such algorithms if they are faster? The existence of temporary variables does not have any say in whether an algorithm is better, even with moves.

Comment: @Justin, no theorem?  I think the theorem would be, "If I do nothing, then it would be faster than doing something".

Comment: @Adrian Doing something sometimes enables you to do other things faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me why you need the lines

```
    size_t iLhs = &lhs - &indices.front();
    size_t iRhs = &rhs - &indices.front();
```

at all. Remove them. Simplify your call to

```
sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(),
     [&] (size_t lhs, size_t rhs) {
         return original[lhs] < original[rhs];
     });
```

Comment: Oh yeah.  Dunno what I was thinking. Smh.

Comment: Still begs the question.  Are the objects being copied prior to actually sorting?

Comment: @Adrian, which objects? The objects in `original`?

Comment: `original` is untouched (can even be `const`).

Comment: @RSahu, no in `indices`, the vector actually being sorted.

Comment: @Adrian, `inices` will be sorted in place. Are you concerned that a copy of `indices` will be made somehow?

Comment: @RSahu, ignore that `indices` is an `vector<size_t>` atm.  if this was a `vector<obj_t>` where `obj_t` is a bit more complex, then this would cause unnecessary copies.

Comment: @Adrian, there will be copying but it won't be needless copying. There is no other way to sort a vector/array of objects.

Comment: s/copying/moving